# jquery get specific id

Tags: php, jquery, json

[image]

I made this for my school project, but my question is now:

i add new cars to my shoppingcart and when i select a different car the first one also changes. all selected cars had his own price but when i select a different car the all the price are same:

My code:

```
            $('.productprijzen').hide();
            var $select = $('<select>').addClass('keuzes');

            $select.append('<option>Kies je optie</option>');
            $select.append('<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>');
            $select.append('<option value="saab">saab</option>');
            $select.append('<option value="peugeot">peugeot</option>');
            $select.append('<option value="mazda">mazda</option>');

            $select.on('change', function ()
            {
                console.log();
                $parent = $(this).closest(".row");
                $('.productprijzen',$parent).slideDown();


                var merk = $(this).val();
                var productInfo = oProducten[merk];
                $('.prijs').html("€" + productInfo.prijs);
                $('.btw').html(productInfo.btw+ "%");
                //$('.aantal').html(productInfo.btw+ "%");

                // berekening van aantal x prijs
                var $aantalKeuze = $('input.aantal');
                var $subtotaal = $('.qty');
                $aantalKeuze.change(function () {
                    $subtotaal.html((productInfo.prijs * $aantalKeuze.val()));
                });
            });

            $product = $(".producttemplate");
            $('.productkeuzes',$product).append($select.clone(true));

            var $i = 1;
            $(".nieuw").click(function () {

                $('.producten').append($product.clone(true).addClass('single product'+$i).removeClass('producttemplate'));
                $i++;
            });
        });
```

Comment: can you provide the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the price,btw,subtotal to the current element only

```
$parent.find('.prijs').html("€" + productInfo.prijs);
$parent.find('.btw').html(productInfo.btw+ "%");
....
$subtotaal = $parent.find('.qty');
```

Comment: not only $subtotaal, the PRICE and BTW need to be unique. when i add new car the first one need to stay at his own value, and the second need to get his own value(price and btw) as well

Comment: @Dimitri yes, as you can see in my answer

Comment: how can i calculate VAT on the prices?

Comment: i don't know how VAT is calculated in your country but in my country you use simple math like price*0.19

Comment: you do someting like `$parent.append('price+VAT'+((productInfo.prijs * $aantalKeuze.val())*VAT/100)) `  where VAT is your VAT %

Comment: i forgot the total price of all product, how can i do that?

Comment: you need to loop over all `$subtotaal` and get the values and sum them